# Bootstrap: Rearranging middle element in vertical stack

Tags: bootstrap-4

First time posting - hi everyone :)

I've been experimenting with bootstrap and have come up against a problem I can't solve while creating what seems to be a simlle component. It's similar to a media object, except that I want the image to be inserted in between the header and any text on smaller breakpoints.

On larger screens:

```
--------------
|     |header|
|image|------|
|     | text |
--------------
```

On smaller screens :

```
--------
|header|
--------
|image |
--------
| text |
--------
```

Each of these is straightforward enough individually, it's getting to get one to transform into the other that I'm struggling with.

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: where is the code to show that try? edit your question and add it

Comment: Don't have it handy I'm afraid, tapping this out on my mobile instead of sleeping - this problem is keeping me awake >.<

Comment: Yep, that seems to do the job. Many thanks!